# How to change font of Square payment form

Tags: javascript, fonts, square, square-connect

I am trying to initialize the square payment form and change the font of the input field.  When using a browser default like serif this argements renders correctly, however when trying to use a Google font I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid InputStyle value `Roboto` for property `fontFamily`.
See: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form/#stylingcardform
    at Object.styleStringForKeyValuePair (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:30543)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:29754)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.styleStringForStyleObject (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:29677)
    at Object.buildStylesForScreenWidth (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:29578)
    at s.buildStylesForScreenWidth (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:16470)
    at new s (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:15723)
    at s (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:9536)
    at r (https://connect.squareup.com/v2/iframe?type=cardNumber:31:9919)
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

```
inputStyles: [{
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
}],

// more initialization parameters
```

The code template is from https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form

Is it possible to use an imported font as an input style?

Comment: While it might not be the cause of your problem, webfonts are downloaded asynchronously, so it's entirely possible that you need to wait for that to finish, using a font loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time you cannot use custom fonts with the payment form. This is something Square is looking into, particularly with Google fonts.

Comment: Ah, bummer.  Do you have a list of supported fonts? Or a timeline for Google fonts support?

Comment: Also, ```textAlign: 'center'``` would be an awesome addition.

Comment: And thanks for all the help with my Square questions :).